# How is "(Integer)getIntent().getExtras().get(x)" different from "(Integer)getIntent().getStringExtra(x)"?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to extract an int from an Intent I created, but the second one throws up an error "Cannot convert java.lang.String to int", while the first one does not. Why does this happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

to get an `int` value you need to use

```
getIntent().getIntExtra("x", 0)
```

or

```
getIntent().getExtras().getInt("x")
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one is:

```
(Integer)getIntent().getExtras().get(x)
```

This retrieves an `Object` based on the key `x` and attempts to cast that to be an `Integer`. If `get()` returns something else, you crash at runtime with a `ClassCastException`.

The second one is:

```
(Integer)getIntent().getStringExtra(x)
```

This retrieves a `String` based on the key `x` and attempts to cast that as an `Integer`. It is possible that an `Object` might be an `Integer`, which is why the first one compiles but might fail at runtime. It is not possible that a `String` is an `Integer`. Hence, this fails at compile time.

The right answer, as Mr. Oleg notes, is to call `getIntExtra()` on the `Intent` or `getInt()` on the `Bundle` returned by `getExtras()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about casting.
getIntent().getExtras().get(x) returns an Object type.
While (Integer)getIntent().getStringExtra(x) returns an String type Object.

If you recall(or just learning), every Java `Class` extends Object by default and thos get it's mehtods such as `toString()`.
This is why you can try to cast Object to ANY class. try - but if it fails you will know it only at run-time.

On the other hand, a `String` is a class that already extends `Object` and has nothing to do with `Integer` and it's own values and properties.
So, when you try to cast from a `String` to a `Integer` you get an error.

The best solution was already published.
I'll just add that you can still do this:

```
getInteger(getIntent().getStringExtra(x));
```